# How to distribute data when odd number of processer cores are allotted in MPI?

Tags: c, mpi

I'm beginner in MPI programming. I'm trying to write a program that dynamically takes in an one dimensional arrays of different sizes (multiples of 100, 1000, 10000, 1000000 and so on) and scatters it to allotted processor cores. Processor cores calculate the sum of the received elements and send the sum back. The root process prints the sum of the elements in input array.

I used `MPI_Scatter()` and `MPI_Reduce()` to solve the problem. However, when the number of processor cores allotted are odd in number, some of the data get left out. For example, when I have input data size of 100 and 3 processes - only 99 elements are added and last one is left out.

I searched for the alternatives and found that `MPI_Scatterv()` can be used for uneven distribution of data. But there is no material available to guide me for it's implementation. Can someone help me? I'm posting my code here. Thanks in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readArray(char * fileName, double ** a, int * n);
int Numprocs, MyRank;
int mpi_err; 
#define Root = 0

void init_it(int  *argc, char ***argv) {
    mpi_err = MPI_Init(argc, argv);
    mpi_err = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyRank);
    mpi_err = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Numprocs);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* .......Variables Initialisation ......*/
    int        index; 
    double    *InputBuffer, *RecvBuffer, sum=0.0, psum = 0.0;
    double     ptime = 0.0, Totaltime= 0.0,startwtime = 0.0, endwtime = 0.0;
    int        Scatter_DataSize;
    int        DataSize;
    FILE       *fp;

    init_it(&argc,&argv);
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n*** Usage: arraySum <inputFile>\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (MyRank == 0) {
        startwtime = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("Number of nodes running %d\n",Numprocs);
        /*...... Read input....*/
        readArray(argv[1], &InputBuffer, &DataSize);
        printf("Size of array %d\n", DataSize);
    }

    if (MyRank!=0) {
        MPI_Recv(&DataSize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL);
    }
    else {
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<Numprocs;i++) {
            MPI_Send(&DataSize, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            d[i]= i*Numprocs;
        }
    }

    Scatter_DataSize = DataSize / Numprocs;
    RecvBuffer = (double *)malloc(Scatter_DataSize * sizeof(double));
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    mpi_err = MPI_Scatter(InputBuffer, Scatter_DataSize, MPI_DOUBLE,
                          RecvBuffer, Scatter_DataSize, MPI_DOUBLE,
                          0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    for (index = 0; index < Scatter_DataSize; index++) {
        psum = psum + RecvBuffer[index];
    }

    //printf("Processor %d computed sum %f\n", MyRank, psum);

    mpi_err = MPI_Reduce(&psum, &sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (MyRank == 0) {
        endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
        Totaltime = endwtime - startwtime;
        printf("Total sum %f\n",sum);
        printf("Total time %f\n", Totaltime);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}


void readArray(char * fileName, double ** a, int * n) {
    int count, DataSize;
    double * InputBuffer;
    FILE * fin;

    fin = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fin == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n*** Unable to open input file '%s'\n\n",
                fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(fin, "%d\n", &DataSize);
    InputBuffer = (double *)malloc(DataSize * sizeof(double));
    if (InputBuffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n*** Unable to allocate %d-length array", DataSize);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (count = 0; count < DataSize; count++) {
        fscanf(fin, "%lf", &InputBuffer[count]);
    }
    fclose(fin);

    *n = DataSize;
    *a = InputBuffer;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by there are no materials? The Internet is full of tutorials about MPI. Also, a good example of `MPI_Scatterv` is given in the MPI standard itself and that is freely available for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you may just play with the `sendcount[]` array of `MPI_Scatterv`. Indeed, a trivial implementation would be to compute the number of element (let say `Nelement`) of type `sendtype` that all the processes but one will reveive. One of the processes (for instance the last one) will get the remaining data. In that case, `sendcount[i] = Nelement` for indexes `i` from `0` to `p-2` (`p` is the number of processes in the communicator, for you `MPI_COMM_WORLD`). Then the process `p-1` will get `sendcount[p-1] = DataSize-Nelement*(p-1)`. Concerning the array of displacements `displs[]`, you have just to specify the displacement (in number of elements) from which to take the outgoing data to process i (cf. [1] page 161). For the previous example this would be:

```
    for (i=0; i<p; ++i)
        displs[i]=Nelement*i;
```

If you decide that another process `q` must compute the other data, think to set the good displacement `displs[q+1]` for the process `q+1` with `0 ≤ q < q+1 ≤ p`.

[1] *MPI: A Message-Passing Interface Standard* (Version 3.1): http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf

Comment: Thank you! Reference material helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The computation of the Scatter_Datasize:

Scatter_DataSize = DataSize / Numprocs;

is correct only if DataSize is a multiple of Numprocs, which in your case, as DataSize is always even, occurs when Numprocs is even. When Numprocs is odd you should explicitly compute the remainder and assign it to one MPI process, i suggest the last.